# What is SCIP, in optimization problems?

Tags: python, optimization, or-tools

Can someone please explain what SCIP is in the following code

```
from ortools.linear_solver import pywraplp
solver = pywraplp.Solver.CreateSolver('SCIP')
```

Comment: I'd suppose it's this solver: https://www.scipopt.org/

Comment: @LaurentPerron If I could find a post that would clearly explain my doubt, I would never ask this question now, would I?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ortools` is a library for creating models. To actually solve the model, it relies on 3rd party solvers, one of which is [SCIP](https://www.scipopt.org/).

The argument to `CreateSolver()` selects the 3rd party solver to use, in this case SCIP.